# Use BigQuery CLI to authenticate two two projects without bq init, like gsutil with a .boto file?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to get the bq CLI to work with multiple service accounts for different projects without having to re-authenticate using gcloud auth login or bq init.

#### An example of what I want to do, and am able to do using gsutil:

I have used gsutil with a .boto configuration file containing:

```
[Credentials]
gs_service_key_file = /path/to/key_file.json
[Boto]
https_validate_certificates = True
[GSUtil]
content_language = en
default_api_version = 2
default_project_id = my-project-id
[OAuth2]
```

on a GCE instance to run an arbitrary gsutil command as a service.  The service does not need to be unique or globally defined on the GCE instance: as long as a service is set up in `my-project-id` and a private key has been created, then the private key file referenced in the .boto config will take care of authentication.  For example, if I run

```
BOTO_CONFIG=/path/to/my/.boto_project_1
export BOTO_CONFIG
gsutil -m cp gs://mybucket/myobject .
```

I can copy from any project that I have a service account set up with, and for which I have the private key file defined in .boto_project_1.  In this way, I can run a similar gsutil command for project_2 just be referencing the .boto_project_2 config file.  No manual authentication needed.

#### The case with bq CLI

In the case of the bigquery command line interpreter, I want to reference a config file or pass a config option like a key file to run a `bq load` command, ie. upload the same .csv file that is in GCS for various projects.  I want to automate this without having to `bq init` each time.

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254479/how-do-i-configure-google-bigquery-command-line-tool-to-use-a-service-account/13255327) that you can configure a .biqqueryrc file and pass in your credential and key files as options; however the answer is from 2012, references outdated bq credential files, and throws errors due to the openssl and pyopenssl installs that it mentioned.

#### My question

Provide two example bq load commands with any necessary options/biqueryrc files to correctly load a .csv file from GCS into bigquery for two distinct projects without needing to bq init/authenticate manually between the two commands.  Assume the .csv file is already correctly in each project's GCS bucket.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `gcloud auth activate-service-account` and use the global `--project` flag.

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/